# Cannot load default values in input fields using FormHelper in cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm facing a very wierd situation concerning a quite simple task.
I'm trying to create a very simple edit form in my application using
cakephp 3.x version.

In my `ContentsController::edit($contentID)` method I'm loading the content entity to be edited like this

```
$content = $this->Contents->findById($contentID)->first()
```

and then I'm simply creating the respective view variable using `set()` method like that:

```
$this->set('content', $content);
```

In the view file - named `edit.ctp` - all I'm doing is to simply create
a new form using `FormHelper` using the following piece of code:

```
<h2><?= __('Edit content: ') . $content->title; ?></h2>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create($content);
echo $this->Form->input('title', ['type' => 'text']);
echo $this->Form->input('alias', ['type' => 'text']);
echo $this->Form->input('body', ['type' => 'textarea']);
echo $this->Form->submit();
?>
```

The following code creates the form correctly but it does not load the default values in each input element from the `$content` entity. After doing some digging into the source code of the `FormHelper` I found out that when the `FormHelper::create()` method is called, it correctly loads the `EntityContext` interface using the `$content` entity. But for some reason, which I cannot explain, in each of the `FormHelper::input()` calls, internally the context interface is switching to `NullContext` so no data is loaded into the field.

Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong with that piece of code?

Comment: Change `$this->Contents->findById($contentID)->first()` for
 `$this->Contents->get($contentID)` here you have [more info](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#editing-articles)

Comment: I thing both are same..post your edit method as well..is that all good ?

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging I found the real cause of the issue.
`FormHelper` works correctly and so does my query.

The issue has to do with the view file and how it is rendered.
The whole picture is this.

My view (`edit.ctp`) was an extension of a common skeleton I created, namely `edit_frm.ctp`. So in my view file I was extending by calling `$this->extend('/Common/edit_frm');`

The structure of the `edit_frm.ctp` consists of three blocks, as shown below (I removed the html markup)

```
<?php
// Common/edit_frm.ctp
$this->fetch('formStart');
$this->fetch('formPrimaryOptions');
$this->fetch('formSecondaryOptions');
$this->fetch('formEnd');
?>
```

Now in my view file (`edit.ctp`) I was creating the blocks like that:

```
<?php
// Contents/edit.ctp
$this->extend('Common/edit_frm');

// The "formStart" block contains the opening of the form
$this->start('formStart');
echo $this->Form->create($content);
$this->end('formStart');

// The "formEnd" block contains the submit button and the form closing tag
$this->start('formEnd');
echo $this->Form->submit();
echo $this->Form->end();
$this->end('formEnd');

// "formPrimaryOptions" contains the main input fields
$this->start('formPrimaryOptions');
echo $this->Form->input('title', ['type' => 'text']);
echo $this->Form->input('alias', ['type' => 'text']);
echo $this->Form->input('body', ['type' => 'textarea']);
$this->end('formPrimaryOptions');
?>
```

As you see in my view file, I was building the `formEnd` block **before** the construction of the `formPrimaryOptions` block. Though in my skeleton the blocks are fetched in a different order.

**Apparently** in CakePHP when you extend a view combined with blocks of content **in the actual view file you must create your blocks in the same order as they are fetched**, otherwise you end up in weird situations like the one I was facing.

In any case, I had a very good lesson today!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this instead of findById:

```
$content = $this->Contents->find('all')->where(['id' => $contentID])->first();
```